# string replace all regex pattern to NOT match if nested

Tags: java, regex, string

consider the scenario below i have an input string

```
"input [yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]"
```

my desired out string after replace all is all `[yes]` will be replaced with `Yes` however if it is nested within a secondary or n-backets such patterns should be ignored, the assumption here is that all opening brackets will be properly closed, here is the desired output string

```
"input Yes Yes Yes [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] Yes [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]"
```

here is my question in a nutshell, can regex understand 'nested' patterns? or is recursion an absolute necessity in doing accomplishing this and regex is simply not sufficient enough

if detecting infinitely nested regex cannot be done, how about nested to the second degree only like my examples

Comment: This can't be done by regex, you need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

As this cannot be done with regex as pointed out by vks, I wrote a simple program that'll do the same for you in Java:

```
public class Main {

    public static String nestedReplace(String s) {
        int nested =0,i=0;
        StringBuilder o = new StringBuilder();
        while(i<s.length())
        {
            if(nested==0 && s.regionMatches(i,"[yes]",0,4))
            {
                o.append("Yes");
                i += 5;
                continue;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == '[')
                nested++;
            else if(s.charAt(i) == ']')
                nested--;
            o.append(s.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        return new String(o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(nestedReplace("input [yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input Yes Yes Yes [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] Yes [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]
```

Comment: This is too fragile!!!!!!! https://regex101.com/r/kO1cB4/2 ... it needs recursive regex which is not supported by java

Comment: actually the pattern is much more complex you answer wont work in here [yes] [no] [yes] [mk:[yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [no] [yes] iifnot [maybe]], that main goal is to detect and replaced only those [yes] that are not nested inside brakets

Comment: @jyonkheel you cannot do it with regex in java.......you will have to write ur own parser

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
\[[^\[\]]+\[.+?][^\[\]]*\]|\[([a-z])[^\[\]]+\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rP3cT1/3)

With this you will match the whole nested brackets, or not-nested bracket. Then replace content only if `Matcher` will find `group(1)` (not nested bracket), like in:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] strings = {"input [yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]",
                "input [yes] [yes] [yes[yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]",
                "input [yes] [yes] [yes[yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]"};

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[\\]]+\\[.+?][^\\[\\]]*\\]|\\[([a-z])[^\\[\\]]+\\]");

        for(String string : strings) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            while (true) {

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
                        string = string.substring(0, matcher.start(1)) + string.substring(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)).toUpperCase() + string.substring(matcher.end(1));
                        matcher.reset(string);
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

which gives output:

```
input [Yes] [Yes] [Yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [Yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]
input [Yes] [Yes] [yes[yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [Yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [Yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]
input [Yes] [Yes] [yes[yes] [yes] [yes] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [mk:[yes] [yes] [yes]] [Yes] [iif:[yes] [yes] [yes]]
```